# How do I do date math in a Django ORM query?

Tags: python, sql, django, python-3.x, orm

I'm using Django with Python 3.7.  I have teh below model ...

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    title = models.TextField(null=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

I would like to write a Django ORM query where I find all articles that are older than 5 minutes.  But I'm not sure how to write such a query. I tried

```
Article.objects.filter((datetime.now(timezone.utc) - created_on)__gte==300)
```

But this results in a

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

error.

Comment: I haven't used it myself but I think "timedelta" is what you are missing -- here are a bunch of examples: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/71121/django.utils.timezone.timedelta, and searching for "django timedelta" on SO will probably get you something.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't see timedelta used in any ORM queries on those examples.  Is that a different page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understandings to read your question. You want to find the list of article which are older than 5 mins considering current time. If am I right than you need to `first subtract 5 mins from your time` and than `make query with greater than or equal (gte) ex:created_on__gte`

Sample code  is given below. Hope this will help

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
date_to_query = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=0, minutes=5)

Article.objects.filter(created_on__gte=date_to_query)
```